# Can anyone help me get Blender stable?

Tags: interface

I am super late on my final because Blender crashes anytime i try using it. It's been buggy since start but it's downright unusable now. I'm only using the factory settings and no plug ins. I have windows 10-64 bit, 24 GB ram, AMD 4.2 GHz quad core. I've pretty much got no hope of passing finals but it'd be real nice to at least submit something.

Comment: ...too few info to understand why it's crashing, but lately win10 gives problems here and there. Please add graphic card info, blender version, and install type (zip, msi, other..). Meanwhile, if you're in a deadline, with your pc, I would quickly create a vm with ubuntu, or mint and try to use blender from there, it would be slower but it could be stable.

Comment: Thanks card is 750ti nvidia Blender 2.78c  msi installer

Comment: I would also try a zip archive, a few times msi may give problems. Just unzip it and run blender.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about your hardware but software.

Some tips you can try:

- reinstall Microsoft C++ 2012
- install the latest version of Blender.
- run Blender as Administrator.

Comment: Well after a reinstall of c++2012 and a restart, blender 2.78c  with out any plugins I'm still crashing. Any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I can't change themes either? Keep getting a trace back. I've wiped blender completely from the registry and still get this odd behaviour. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: @Kent318 A python traceback? Or..? Is it possible you could include the traceback in the question?

Comment: Can you try installing / updating the OpenCL SDK. 
found the solution from this link:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?419626-Blender-2-78c-crashes-upon-startup-(fresh-install-on-new-system)

Comment: I'm so sorry never got a notification issue was a known bug in the end ty so much

Answer (score 0):

Known bug in that blender version was the answer again sorry for not closing this long ago notifications here could use improvement possibly btw

Comment: Very kind of you too leave it so long ty an again sorry